# window.onbeforeunload is not working in Maxthon?

Tags: javascript, maxthon

```
var Okay = false;

window.onbeforeunload = function () {

var status = $("#statusId").val();

if (!Okay && status == 1) {

     return "Are you sure you want to close the window?";
    }
}
```

window.onbeforeunload is working fine in Chrome, but its not working in Maxthon. Is their any replacement for window.onbeforeunload that work both in Chrome and Maxthon Browers.

Comment: I wanted to use `onbeforeunload` a few years back, and found it *very* unreliable, for example it wasn't firing in special conditions in certain browsers, and some other issues. Maybe this changed by now, but I would recommend doing good research before using this.

Comment: onunload should solve the issue

Comment: May I ask what you want to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

No, `onbeforeunload` is not fired on Maxthon.

You can solve this issue catching the `onunload` event.